# Laravel route not working when posting data via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to validate my form with jquery. When submitting, Laravel can't find the route in web.php. When I previous did it with just model::Form, it worked.. Did tried a lot of things but none gave me a solution

**EDIT: 419 execption is gone: facing 500 internal error now**

web.php:

```
Route::post('/profile/sendmail', 'VendorController@send_mail')->name('profile.sendmail');
```

VendorController:

```
public function send_mail(Request $request){
        dd("test");
    }
```

contact.blade.php

```
<div class="events single-event">
    <div class="o-grid">
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                <h4>@lang('profile.contactTitle')</h4>
            </div>


            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm" id="alert_modal" style="margin-top: 150px; display: none">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Alert</h3>
                    <h5 id="alert_message"></h5>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="profile_id" value="{{ $profile->id }}">
            </div>


            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('', __('profile.contactSalutation').'*') !!}
                @if( Session::get('urlLang') == "en" )
                    {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Miss' => 'Miss', 'Sir' => 'Sir'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
                @else
                    {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Frau' => 'Frau', 'Herr' => 'Herr'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
                @endif
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                <p style="color: #696978; font-size: 14px; text-align: right">@lang('profile.mandatoryField')</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="o-grid">
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_first_name', __('profile.contactFirstName').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_first_name', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactFirstName'),'class' => 'c-input required','id' => 'contact_first_name','required']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_e_mail', __('profile.contactEmail').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_e_mail', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactEmail'),'class' => 'c-input required email','id' => 'contact_e_mail','required']) !!}
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('contact_e_mail') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_last_name', __('profile.contactLastName').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_last_name', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactLastName'),'class' => 'c-input required','id' => 'contact_last_name','required']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_phone', __('profile.contactPhone')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_phone', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactPhone'),'class' => 'c-input','id' => 'contact_phone']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col">
                {!! Form::label('text', __('profile.contactMessageInfo')) !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('contact_text',null,['class' => 'c-input c-input__text required','placeholder' => __('profile.contactMessageInfo'),'id' => 'contact_text','required']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
            <input class="c-input__checkbox required" id="toc" type="checkbox" name="agree_to_toc" value="1" required>
            <label class="c-input__checkboxLabel p2" for="toc">
                {!! @trans('global.formTacInfo', [
                    'class' => 'c-link c-link__primary',
                    'link_datenschutz' => route('static.show', ['folder_id' => 28, 'slug' => "datenschutz"])
                    ]) !!}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="o-grid__col u-text-right">
            <button id="submit_contact_form" class="c-btn c-btn--small c-btn--red" type="submit" style="display: none" onclick="submitForm()">
                <span>@lang('profile.contactSendMessage')</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#toc').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#submit_contact_form').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#submit_contact_form').hide();
        }
    })

    function submitForm() {
        var profile_id = $("#profile_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{route("profile.sendmail")}}',
            data: {profile_id: profile_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $('#alert_message').text(data.message);
                $('#alert_modal').show();
            },
            error: function(data){
                $('#alert_message').text(data.message);
                $('#alert_modal').show();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

On your post route you dont need to pass variables in the URL:

Change your route to:

```
Route::post('/profile/sendmail', 'VendorController@send_mail')->name('profile.sendmail');
```

And the ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: '{{route("profile.sendmail")}}',
                    data: {profile_id_var: profile_id_var},
```

On your controller:

```
$request->get('profile_id_var');
```

Comment: That helped a bit, in my header he now gives "profile_id => 409" (409 =the number). But still get the 419 status.. thanks!

Comment: Is not reaching the controller?
Check the 'send_mail()' function

Comment: no.. first line is a dd("test"). This is him:
public function send_mail(Request $request,VendorProfile $profile_id){
        dd("f");
}

Comment: Try it

send_mail(Request $request){
dd("f");
}

Comment: 419 is now gone due to the x-csrf header. I tried the controller as well, now having a 500 internal error..

Comment: On the Network tab from DevTools, can you show the error?

Comment: isn't there a way to pass the profile_id in the url? So I can direct access the profile

Comment: Change the route do GET instead of POST, them you will pass via URL.
But on network you can see what the controller is returning to you

Comment: when changing the controller to the old with vendorprofile $profile. I get error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) argh. Just need to get the profile

Comment: `419` status is because missing the `_token` attribute in form requests  try adding `_token` property to `data`                                                               
         `data: {
              profile_id_var : profile_id_var,
              _token : "{{csrf_token()}}"

            }`

Answer (score 2):

The 419 status is usualy related to token problems.

try changing the `'_token'`

to this:

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that's something I saw a lot, but then I get:
VM322:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at m (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Re (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (contact-provider.js:19)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @belgiums , Could you not minify your js and show where the error is reported? In what exat line.

Comment: you mean jquery.min.js? it's just the basic js file? my own js is at the question

Comment: On ajax request:
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },

Comment: the 419 error is gone. I put it as first js script:
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
now having a 500 exception. Trying to solve it :)

Comment: @belgiums and if you return a simple string instead of a `dd()`?

Comment: No error now! but doesn't do anything ofcourse. 
So now, I need to get the Vendorprofile from the profile_id, working on it ;) thanks

Comment: @belgiums Good job man. If one of the answers solved your problem, mark as the correct one so other people don't answer a solved problem =)

Answer (score 0):

I think your line `data: profile_id_var` is not right as you defined your route with a `profile_id` parameter (and not `profile_id_var`).

What if you try `data: { profile_id: profile_id_var }`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
      url: '/post-comments',// the right way;
      url: 'post-comments' // the wrong way because its call the route when we are and not the route when we need to send.
```